# Unable to debug a Gradle + Dropwizard Project from IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, dropwizard

I am currently unable to debug an application that uses gradle + dropwizard from IntelliJ IDEA

I imported the project using the JetGradle plugin and I am launching the "run" task in debug mode from the plugin itself.

I am using this sample project:

https://github.com/quad/dropwizard-gradle

The project actually runs but the breakpoints are never hit.

Anything I may be missing that prevents me from debugging this simple app from IntelliJ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be many reasons why the debugger isn't stopping at a breakpoint, and from your description it's unclear if the problem is related to (Jet)Gradle. That said, the JetGradle plugin in IDEA 12 is very limited, and I recommend to use Gradle's `idea` plugin instead. Alternatively, try an early access preview of IDEA 13, which has a much improved Gradle integration.

Comment: Effectively using IDEA 13 it now works without any change ... using IDEA 12 I had to use remote debugging to actually attach to the correct VM